Count matching elements after splitting
I want to combine std::views::split or std::views::lazy_split with std::ranges::count but I cannot get it to work.
This is what I currently have:
std::string setting;
std::string extension;

const auto count = std::range::count(setting | std::views::split(' '), extension);

And unfortunately the MSVC error is not really helpful:

error C3889: call to object of class type 'std::ranges::_Count_fn': no matching call operator found

How can I count the elements that match extension after splitting (without having to store the parts into a container)?

Use something like for (auto&& word : setting | std::views::split(' ')) to iterate through the splits and count up if they match extension?

That's a workaround but I'd thought there would be a shorter solution with views and ranges.

@NathanOliver Actually, I'd be interested to know why this does not work - what requirements are missing from the split view to be usable in count?

I believe the issue is the split view is essentially a 2D container so when count gets the beginning iterator that iterator just points to another range and count cant handle that since its expecting an object to match with extension.

The subranges after the split cannot be compared with string, so the constraint is not satisfied.
You can use the projection to project them into string_views, which makes them comparable to strings:
std::string setting;
std::string extension;

const auto count = std::ranges::count(
    setting | std::views::split(' '), 
    extension,
    [](auto r) { return std::string_view(r.data(), r.size()); }
);

Or with views::transform:
const auto count = std::ranges::count(
    setting | std::views::split(' ')
            | std::views::transform(
                [](auto r) { return std::string_view(r.data(), r.size()); }),
    extension
);


That does not seem to compile with either MSVC or clang due to std::string_view(r) not being valid (I'm using C++20).

Ok just tested with clang, this seems to require C++23 for the std::string_view constructor unfortunately.

@Holt Yes, I updated the answer for the C++20.

Thanks, I did the same after looking https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view (I used .data() instead of .begin()).

@Holt That's my typo.

I always forget about the projection part of ranges.  Lets us do so many neat things.

std::string and std::string_view are not currently equality comparable to range::split_view or ragne::lazy_split_view elements. I would go for count_if with equal perdicate:
const auto count = std::range::count_if
                 ( setting
                 | std::views::split(' ')
                 , std::bind_front( std::ranges::equal
                                  , std::cref(extension) )
);

All C++20, no iterators or explicit loops.
A more strict approach would use std::string::compare as perdicate:
const auto count = std::range::count_if
                 ( setting
                 | std::views::split(' ')
                 , [&extension](auto const& r)
                 { return not extension.compare(r); }
);

